# material-ui production build broken

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to build into production the create-react-app from material-ui@next (v1-beta branch) but the build is broken. I can't see the app after build finishes so I can't make it live on my gh-pages. Would anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It's working. I had a typo in the json homepage link